Why are all my paragraphs rotated and windowed?
When I send a Word docx file to Kindle, or use the desktop Kindle Creator app, it makes a single page for every single paragraph and rotates each one 90 degrees. This looks like this:

and of course makes the document unusable.
I can't find any setting in Word that makes a difference, nor any way at all to make an ebook that doesn't have this problem.
What could I be doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Consider using something like Calibre to manage your library and convert your Word docs to Kindle format before sideloading to your Kindle. If you're just sending the docx to your Kindle directly, it may be a problem with Amazon's converter.

I did give up on the automatic one and found a tool that handled it properly, which is reasonable for publication. But that's more work that I want to do for just popping a doc onto my Kindle so I can read it. So I'd still like to find a way to prepare a Word doc and send it without this happening.
